# Forms Authetnication works with Forms Authentication disabled in IIS

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, iis-6

I have an application, which uses Forms Based Authentication.  I have never used this before.  Here is sample sample code:

```
private bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password, string strConnectionString)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            string lookupPassword = null;

            // Check for invalid userName.
            // userName must not be null and must be between 1 and 15 characters.
            if ((null == userName) || (0 == userName.Length) || (userName.Length > 15))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of userName failed.");
                return false;
            }

            // Check for invalid passWord.
            // passWord must not be null and must be between 1 and 25 characters.
            if ((null == passWord) || (0 == passWord.Length) || (passWord.Length > 25))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Input validation of passWord failed.");
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                // Consult with your SQL Server administrator for an appropriate connection
                // string to use to connect to your local SQL Server.
                //conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstringremoved);
                conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString)

                conn.Open();
                Error.Text = "Got here";

                // Create SqlCommand to select pwd field from users table given supplied userName.
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select pwd from users where uname=@userName", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
                cmd.Parameters["@userName"].Value = userName;

                // Execute command and fetch pwd field into lookupPassword string.
                lookupPassword = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                // Cleanup command and connection objects.
                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Add error handling here for debugging.
                // This error message should not be sent back to the caller.
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("[ValidateUser] Exception " + ex.ToString());
               Error.Text = ex.ToString();

            }

            // If no password found, return false.
            if (null == lookupPassword)
            {
                // You could write failed login attempts here to event log for additional security.
                return false;
            }

            // Compare lookupPassword and input passWord, using a case-sensitive comparison.
            return (0 == string.Compare(lookupPassword, passWord, false));

        }
```

I have published this application to IIS 6.1 and I have noticed that it works regardless of whether Forms Authentication is enabled or not (it is disabled in the case below).

[image]

I have the same question about Basic Authentication.

I believe it has something to do with Anonymous Authentication being enabled i.e. enabling Anonymous Authentication also enables Forms Authentication by default - or something like that.  However, I cannot find any documentation to support this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **Anonymous Authentication** enabled.

This effectively means that you have NO authentication, as **Anonymous Authentication** allows everybody in.

Comment: When I enable Forms Authentication only, there is an error: The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.  This is in the 404.15 page response.

Comment: So that tells us that the Forms Authentication does kick in indeed and it no longer "works regardless of whether Forms Authentication enabled or not". So you will now have to move onto the next stage and figure out how  to get around your 404.15 page response...